# Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync returns AccessRestricted in Outlook form Mac

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We've developed an add-in for outlook the uses getUserIdentityTokenAsync to identify user. One client gets this error  when calling Office.context.mailbox.getUserIdentityTokenAsync from Outlook on Mac:

```
{
  "status": "failed",
  "error": {
    "name": "AccessRestricted",
    "message": "Intern protokolfejl: '-2147467259'.",
    "code": 9017
  },
  "diagnostics": {
    "InvokeCodeResult": -2147467259
  }
}
```

and Office.context.diagnostics is

```
{
  "host": "Outlook",
  "version": "16.72.409.0",
  "platform": "Mac"
}
```

I have a mac with excatly same version of Outlook (connected to a different tenant), and that works fine

What would cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting. We have already fixed this bug and the fix is being rolled out. It should be available for everyone within 2 weeks.